# Additively cancelative semirings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request

How are they called the semirings verifying that, if for any elements $a,b,c$, if $a+b=a+c$, then $b=c$? Additively cancelative is quite long and I did not find any reference. Substractive seems to mean another thing.

I am sure it is known that such semirings are the semirings that can be embedded into a ring. I will appreciated a reference.

Comment: Additively cancellative seems like the obvious term.  It is used here [on the first page](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-030-03/S0002-9939-1971-0289584-6/S0002-9939-1971-0289584-6.pdf) for example.

Comment: [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43998745) they call it that but also alias it to “halfring”.  Not sure if that one has caught on…. I’d search Gonrdran and mineaux book on semirings too.